# Sequential background processing with Gearman

Tags: symfony, gearman

I have 4 activities (currently as Symfony Commands) that I want to run **sequentially** every 5 hours (that will take around 30 minutes all in all).

I am wondering how this can be achieved with Gearman. Should I, to ensure sequential processing, create a worker with 4 functions which then gets triggered by a Client every 5 hours?

Thanks a lot for any answer.
Steffen

Answer (score 0):

I have a answer and suggestion for your questions.

First of all, MessageQue systems like **Gearman** are suitable for Background processing jobs which are to be done at the moment in a non-blocking way.

If your requirement is to run this every 5 hours, then I guess, **CRONJOBS** are ideal for this kind of situation.
Refer for some more details: [Scheduling with gearman vs. cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961995/scheduling-with-gearman-vs-cron)

If you have some very important reasons to use the **GEARMAN**, then yes, you should create a worker and set the cron job to call the worker every 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

if you add the gearman jobs with the same task ID, they'll run sequentially